# I tried to put a JLabel on a JButton but when I put my mouse pointer on the label it disappears

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

Here I implement a `JButton`:

```java
btnTotalCall = new JButton("Total calls");
        btnTotalCall.setFocusPainted(false);
        btnTotalCall.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
        btnTotalCall.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        btnTotalCall.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        btnTotalCall.setBounds(302, 39, 125, 125);
        contentPane.add(btnTotalCall);
```

Here a `JLabel`:

```java
lblTotalCall = new JLabel("");
        lblTotalCall.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblTotalCall.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        lblTotalCall.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        lblTotalCall.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 20));
        lblTotalCall.setBounds(302, 39, 125, 125);
        contentPane.add(lblTotalCall);
```

Here in a `MainController` I tried to update `lblTotalCall` with my database all the seconds:

```java
public MainController(MainView mainView)
    {
        this.mainView = mainView;

        ActionListener timerListener = new ActionListener()
        {
            DAO<Call> call_dao = new CallDAO();
            List<Call> call_list;
            int call_time;
            DAO<User> user_dao = new UserDAO();
            List<User> user_list;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                // Put the current date and time in the label date and update it
                DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                DateFormat heureFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                Date cal = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                mainView.getLblDate().setText("<html>" + dateFormat.format(cal).toString() + "<br>" +
                                heureFormat.format(cal) + "</html>");

                call_list = call_dao.recupAll();

                        // Update the lblTotalCall
                if(call_list.size() > 0)
                {
        mainView.getLblTotalCall().setText(Integer.toString(call_list.size()));
                }
                else
                {
                    mainView.getLblTotalCall().setText("0");
                }


                for (Call call : call_list) 
                {
                    if (call.getDate() == cal && mainView.getRdbtnToday().isSelected())
                    {
                        call_time = call_time + call.getDuration();
                        call_time = call_time / call_list.size();
                    }
                }

                user_list = user_dao.recupAll();

                if(user_list.size() > 0)
                {
                    mainView.getLblOperators().setText(Integer.toString(user_list.size()));
                }
                else
                {
                    mainView.getLblOperators().setText("0");
                }
            }
        };

        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, timerListener);
        // to make sure it doesn't wait one second at the start
        timer.setInitialDelay(0);
        timer.start();
    }
```

I've already tried to put a default value in the `JLabel`, and change the value of the properties `focusable` and `enabled` to false but that's not fix it.

I launch the application, (sorry I can't post images)

[image]

I see the right data but when I put my mouse pointer on the `btnTotalCall` or `btnOperators` the labels disapear.

[image]

Comment: I don't think the API supports this.

Comment: If the API dont support this, do you think i can try with a JLabel "button" ?

Comment: Why do you need a JLabel over your JButton? JButton already supports many of the features of JLabel such as setting the text and changing the text and background colors.

Comment: The text in the button is hard to manipulate, i have to edit it in html while witrh a `JLabel` i just have to put `String` data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to put a Jlabel on a Jbutton

All I see is:

```
contentPane.add(btnTotalCall);
...
contentPane.add(lblTotalCall);
```

Which means you are adding two components to a panel, not adding a label to a button.

> but when i put my mouse pointer on the jlabel is disappear

By default Swing assumes components do not overlap and when you move the mouse over the button the button needs to be repainted to paint the mouse over effect of the button, so the entire button is repainted and you no longer see the label.

If you want to paint two components in the same place then you need to override the `isOptimizedDrawingEnabled()` method of the panel to return `false` to make sure both components are repainted.

See: [Overlap Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/26/overlap-layout/) for a layout manager that will allow you to stack multiple components on top of one another, once you override the above method.

Or a simpler approach is to add the label to the button:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Total Calls");
button.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.TOP);
button.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

JLabel center = new JLabel("0");
center.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
button.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

This is not a true layout manager as the size of the button will only be determined by the properties of the button, not the label added to the button.

Another option is to use HTML for the text of the button:

```
JButton button2 = new JButton("<html>Total Calls<br><br><center>0</center></html>");
```

Comment: Oh okay i understand, i also make my `JLabel` clickable with a `MouseListener`, i think this is prettier for the user but i will test to add my `JLabel` on my `JButton`. Thanks !

Comment: Ok i changed my `JLabel` "Button" on `JButton` and add it my `JLabel` and that's work, thanks a lot !